# How to use Plumber in an API to upload multiple images to a sub directory?

Tags: r, image, api, plumber

I have sub directory whose location is 'data/images/' and I need my API service to upload images into that sub directory. I am using R and Plumber here. I understand the basic setup, but I can't seem to get my code to deliver my uploaded files into my directory.

This is my attempt:

library(plumber)
library(Rook)

```
#* Upload file
#* @param req:[file]
#* @post /uploadfile
function(req, res){
  
  names(req) 

  print(names(req))

  fileInfo <- list(formContents = Rook::Multipart$parse(req))

  print(fileInfo)

  ## The file is downloaded in a temporary folder
  tmpfile <- fileInfo$formContents$upload$tempfile

  ## Copy the file to a new folder, with its original name
  fn <- file.path(paste0("data/images/",req, sepp=''))
  file.copy(tmpfile, fn)
  print(fn)



  ## Send a message with the location of the file
  res$body <- paste0("Your file is now stored in ", fn, "\n")
  res
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does it print on `print(fn)` ? And on `list.files(fn)` ?

Comment: I don't think the code gets to there. I get this error when i try to upload a file:
<simpleError in paste0("data/images/", req, sepp = ""): environments cannot be coerced to other types>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bunch of pulled hairs, this is essentially the code that makes allows you upload pictures to a designated sub directory. This code needs the plumber and Rook packages to work:

```
library(plumber)
library(Rook)

#* @param req:[file]
#* @post /upload_test27

function(req, res) {

  # Required for multiple file uploads
  names(req)

  # Parses into a Rook multipart file type;needed for API conversions
  fileInfo <- list(formContents = Rook::Multipart$parse(req))

  # This is where the file name is stored
  # print(fileInfo$formContents$req$filename)
  file_name <- fileInfo$formContents$req$filename

  # The file is downloaded in a temporary folder
  tmpfile <- fileInfo$formContents$req$tempfile



  # Create a file path
  fn <- (paste0("data/images/",file_name, sepp=''))


  #Copies the file into the designated folder
  file.copy(tmpfile, fn)


  res$body <- paste0("Your file is now stored in ", fn, "\n")
  res



}
```